# каким членом предложения является "что говорить"

Tags: орфография, синтаксис, члены-предложения

Каким членом предложения является

> Хороший муж, **что говорить**.

Answer (score 3):

**Что и говорить**

***вводное выражение***

**То же, что «конечно».** Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

> Знатно жил *что и говорить.* **С. Черный, Солдатские сказки.** Ну, *что и говорить,* Лотарий был счастлив, счастлив и счастлив. **К. Аксаков, Облако.** И приятности нет как у того, и туг на поводу – *что и говорить!* **И. Тургенев, Конец Чертопханова.**

**Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.**